# Incorrect lighting of a bone-animated object on OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I imported a simple animated object from Blender on three bones. I have a problem with lighting of skinning object. I set a light position above the object:

```
const vec3 lightPosition = vec3(0.0, 15.0, 0.0);
```

You can see that lighting is affected under object too:

[image]

```
precision mediump float;

attribute vec3 aPosition;
attribute vec4 aNormal;
attribute vec2 aTexCoord;
attribute vec3 aJoints;
attribute vec3 aWeights;

uniform mat4 uMvpMatrix;
uniform mat4 uModelMatrix;
uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;
uniform mat4 uTransforms[3];

varying vec3 vPosition;
varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main()
{
    vec4 totalLocalPos = vec4(0.0);
    vec4 totalNormal = vec4(0.0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int jointIndex = int(aJoints[i]);
        mat4 jointTransform = uTransforms[jointIndex];
        vec4 posePosition = jointTransform * vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
        totalLocalPos += posePosition * aWeights[i];

        vec4 worldNormal = jointTransform * aNormal;
        totalNormal += worldNormal * aWeights[i];
    }
    
    gl_Position = uMvpMatrix * totalLocalPos;
    vPosition = vec3(uModelMatrix * vec4(aPosition, 1.0));
    vNormal = totalNormal.xyz;
    vTexCoord = aTexCoord;
}
```

```
precision mediump float;

const vec3 lightColor = vec3(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
const vec3 lightPosition = vec3(0.0, 15.0, 0.0);
const vec3 ambientLight = vec3(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);

uniform sampler2D uSampler;

varying vec3 vPosition;
varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture2D(uSampler, vTexCoord);
    vec3 normal = normalize(vNormal);
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(lightPosition - vPosition);
    float nDotL = max(dot(lightDirection, normal), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = lightColor * color.rgb * nDotL;
    vec3 ambient = ambientLight * color.rgb;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(diffuse + ambient, color.a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Aroch** helped me on Russian forum [here](https://gamedev.ru/code/forum/?id=263724&m=5447490#m1):

> the normal only needs to be rotated.

Now it works as it should. I took shaders (except lighting model) from source for a [video tutorial series from ThinMatrix](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLRIWtICgwaX2tKWCxdeB7Wv_rTET9JtWW). It works fine for ThinMatrix. This means that for some reason its lighting model is not affected by the translation of the normal vector. It will be necessary to figure out later why he does not have this problem. I made the transfer of the array of rotation matrices a separate uniform:

```
uniform mat4 uTransforms[3];
uniform mat4 uRotations[3];

...

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int jointIndex = int(aJoints[i]);
        mat4 jointTransform = uTransforms[jointIndex];
        vec4 posePosition = jointTransform * vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
        totalLocalPos += posePosition * aWeights[i];

        mat4 rotation = uRotations[jointIndex];
        vec4 worldNormal = rotation * aNormal;
        totalNormal += worldNormal * aWeights[i];
    }
```

Gif Animation: https://gamedev.ru/files/images/solution-with-lighting.gif

[image]